# .Net Framework 4.5.3 missing from targeting list in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

I have installed .Net Framework 4.5.3 on my machine but Visual Studio is not showing this version in targeting list. 
the thing that is happening is that I am loading a project that needs .Net Framework 4.5.3 . While loading, VS tells me that I have to Either change it to 4.5 or download the version required. choosing the download option opens browser with this link:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12485&pver=12&sbp=TargetPackMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.3

which does not open and redirects me to microsoft home page.

any solutions?

Comment: That was an old CTP version, it was replaced by 4.6.  There are no targeting packs for it, the one for 4.6 isn't going to be available until VS2015 is ready.  Probably around the summer.  If you are taking projects from somebody else then you need to agree about the CTP version you both use.  Ask the other guy to update his.